# Prestashop message "No template found for module"

Tags: wamp, prestashop

I have created a Prestashop module that works perfectly on a WAMP server, but does not work properly on a live server, instead returning the "No template found for module" error message. I will supply more details later if necessary, but firstly can someone give me suggestions as to why this would be happening, as I have no idea how to begin fixing it. Thanks

The module is designed to work with selected categories only - and it does work well with those categories, both with WAMP and live, but the problem is with the un-selected categories were it should return the product-list file which is in the include file {include file="./product-list.tpl" products=$products}, but instead I get this "No template found for module" message.

The code in my module that calls the file is: return $this->display(**FILE**, '../../product-list.tpl');

This path works on WAMP, but not live. I have tested the path - with a default template - in different folders and it works, but as soon as I put the template inside the themes folder it does not work.

Another thing I have tried is to upgraded the php version, as my WAMP server ran php version 5.5.12 and my server was 5.4 so I changed it to 5.5 but still it did not help.  Thanks

Comment: Usually it's a problem with capital letters in filenames. Windows do not differentiate letter cases for filenames but linux does.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, but unfortunately I have already tried that!

Comment: Well then you'll need to give us more details. On what page is it happening, maybe some code... You can also try clearing cache in backoffice.

Answer (score 3):

Your details are still unclear but here is how the `$this->display(__FILE__, 'template.tpl')` method loads a template. It tries to find and load a file in this order (1.6 version):

1. `/themes/active_theme_name/modules/module_name/template.tpl`
2. `/themes/active_theme_name/modules/module_name/views/templates/hook/template.tpl`
3. `/themes/active_theme_name/modules/module_name/views/templates/front/template.tpl`
4. `/modules/module_name/views/templates/hook/template.tpl`
5. `/modules/module_name/views/templates/front/template.tpl`
6. `/modules/module_name/template.tpl`

If a file is not found in any of these 6 steps, prestashop will throw `No template found for module` error.

Also by adding `../../` before a template name causes the method to search that file in two folders up the directory tree for every step.

Comment: Prestashop is not having trouble finding my template, which is in the 2 option in your list, it is failing to return the product-list.tpl with un-selected categories. A bit more information that may help is, in the category.tpl I have replaced {include file="./product-list.tpl" products=$products} with my display hook. Therefore when a category is NOT selected the code in the hook then returns the file product-list.tpl.

Comment: Yes and the code in hook which tries to load `product-list.tpl` cannot load it because it's not in any of those directories in the answer.

Comment: Hello again, The product-list.tpl is in themes/active-theme-name/ which is not one of the directories in your list, but why then does it work perfectly with a WAMP server? That is what is causing me so much confusion.

Comment: It is weird yes, I guess the only thing left is to open file `/classes/module/Module.php`, find method `_isTemplateOverloadedStatic()` on line 2243 and put code this at the beginning of method: `p(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/'.$template);p(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/views/templates/hook/'.$template);p(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/views/templates/front/'.$template);p(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/views/templates/hook/'.$template);p(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/views/templates/front/'.$template);p(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/'.$template);`.

Comment: And then load the page with "un-selected" (whatever that means) category to display which paths it's trying to load.

Comment: I will give your suggestion a try, but first I wanted to clarify 'unselected'. The categories I want to use my module are selected via a category tree in the back-office. The ones that I don't want to use the module are 'unselected'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line to display template file with

```
$this->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_, 'MODULE_NAME/views/templates/product-list.tpl');
```

For example, if the folder name of the module is 'supercheckout' and the file exist in

```
/modules/supercheckout/views/templates/product-list.tpl
```

Then the line of code will be

```
$this->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_, 'supercheckout/views/templates/product-list.tpl');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the product-list.tpl template is not in a module it is in my theme folder as in themes/mytheme/product-list.tpl.